# What standard specifies inner structure of the query component in HTTP URI

Tags: http, uri

According to RFC3986 (URI),

```
The query component is indicated by the first question
mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
or by the end of the URI.
```

And specifies what characters are allowed inside. That's generic URI.

In daily interaction with various HTTP/Web servers, in URI `http` scheme, we're seeing query components represented as `key=value` pairs separated by `&` sign. RFC7230 (HTTP/1.1) says nothing about it, just that the content of the query component corresponds to RFC3986 generic definition.

The only standard defining said key-value pairs is HTML 4.01 while talking about content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It's also the only standard saying `+` should be treated as Space character in the query component.

However, as far as I could dig up in the specs, `Content-Type` header only applies to the message body, not its URI. And when, as an experiment, I'm googling for "asd zxc" Chrome sends the request `/search?q=zxc+asd` to Google without specifying said `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type at all.

Is it just conventional or am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting question, u may find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520996/parameter-separator-in-urls-the-case-of-misused-question-mark, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481664/semicolon-as-url-query-separator