# How to use rest apis when using two parameters to the same method call?

Tags: java, rest, restful-url

I have rest url with:    `xxxxx/12134?includeaddress=true`
Here `12134` is the `contactid`

And `xxxxx/?$taxid?includeaddress=true` is an other parameter to fetch the results from the same method call.

So I have a situation where I would need put a same rest path which would take either of the parameters(contactid or taxid) .
Can I write both the parameters in the same link

any help is appreciated !

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter separator in urls, the case of misused question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520996/parameter-separator-in-urls-the-case-of-misused-question-mark)

Answer (score -1):

Start the query parameters with `?` and delimeter them with `&` so:

```
https://some.api.com?hello=world&foo=bar
```

Where the 2 parameters are `hello` and `foo` and their values are `world` and `bar` respectively.